# Получение позиции мышки в canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Надо получить позицию мышки в canvas. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот по канвасу примеры:

[Собственно источник](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/)

```js
function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.font = '18pt Calibri';
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
  writeMessage(canvas, message);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```